# First time using classes - what am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Parser():
        html_escape_table = {
            "&": "&amp;",
            '"': "&quot;",
            "'": "&apos;",
            ">": "&gt;",
            "<": "&lt;",
            }
        def html_escape(text):
            return "".join(html_escape_table.get(c,c) for c in text)
        def query():
            database = [x, y, z, etc, etc2]
            for x in database:
                html_escape(x)
                print x #for testing purposes
                return
test = Parser()

test.query()
```

Am I doing this correctly? I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: query() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I'm not seeing anywhere where I am passing an argument to query, or even to Parser.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

I tried calling just Parser.query() and got this error (this was after adding the self argument to all of my functions and object argument to my Parser class)

```
    Parser.query()
TypeError: unbound method query() must be called with Parser instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: A class always passes a reference to itself as the first argument. change `query()`'s definition to `def query(self):`

Comment: You should read the Python tutorial, which explains all this.

Comment: Wait, if `query` doesn't use anything within a `Parser` object, then why are you writing it as a method of `Parser`? Why not keep it as a function in the same file outside the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods in classes require the argument `self` this is to do with parsing the instance to the method in how python does instance methods.

e.g.

```
class Test(object):
    def say_hello(self):
        print "Hi there"
```

Just to expand on this if you want to parse arguments to an instance method you still need `self`

```
class Test(object):
    def say_hello(self, name):
        print "Hi %s" % name
```

Edit:

Okay to explain it further you have to know how python handles instances, python handles instances in a very verbose and clear way, `self` is always used to refer to itself or this current instance, just like `this` in Java. So when python calls `my_instance.method()` its actually calling `TheObject.method(my_instance)` hence why self refers to the `my_instance` inside the method. That allows you to use the instance inside the method with the instance itself passed around inside the arugments.

Edit 2:

Even when you have self as an argument to the methods you need to call it from an instance like so

```
my_parser = Parser()
my_parser.method()
```

Edit 3:

This isn't Java you don't have to bind your functions together as methods inside a class, just leave them as free-roaming functions inside a parser.py file then you can do

```
import parser
parser.do_this()
```

Comment: Can you explain this concept further? I don't entirely understand it. Basically I'm calling an instance of the method, and I have to use self to refer to the instance of the method, as opposed to the actual method?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Tried to explain it better

Answer (score 4):

With Python, class methods must have their first parameter be `self`

```
class Parser(): # Creates a class that contain all of the functions that parse the mood based on tweets
    html_escape_table = {
            "&": "&amp;",
            '"': "&quot;",
            "'": "&apos;",
            ">": "&gt;",
            "<": "&lt;",
    }
    def html_escape(self, text):
        return "".join(html_escape_table.get(c,c) for c in text)
    def query(self):
        database = [x, y, z, etc, etc2]
        for x in database:
            html_escape(x)
            print x #for testing purposes
            return

test = Parser()

test.query()
```

Answer (score 2):

One small thing: If you start using classes in Python (at least in Python 2.x, Python 3 is different), you might want to use new style classes, which inherit from `object`.

Python 2.x classes, new style:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        # some code here

    # more methods here
```

The old style classes (without the `object`) should not be used anymore in current versions in Python 2.

If you are working with Python 3, it's different. Classes are one of the concepts that have had a cleanup in Python 3, so there is no need to inherit from `object` anymore. So if you are learning to use classes in Python, make sure the instructions you get are for the correct version (mainly 2 vs 3 that is).

Comment: Unless your in Python3 then `object` is intrinsic

Comment: @JakobBowyer Okay, guess you are right. I changed it, now it should stand out. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 2):

In any object-oriented language, methods have to have a way to access the object on which they were called.  In some languages, this is done implicitly.  In Python, methods have to be declared with an explicit first `self` parameter.

Here I've fixed your code to have the `self` parameters.

```
class Parser():
    """A class that contain all of the functions that parse the mood based on tweets."""
    html_escape_table = {
        "&": "&amp;",
        '"': "&quot;",
        "'": "&apos;",
        ">": "&gt;",
        "<": "&lt;",
        }
    def html_escape(self, text):
        return "".join(self.html_escape_table.get(c,c) for c in text)

    def query(self):
        database = [x, y, z, etc, etc2]
        for x in database:
            self.html_escape(x)
            print x #for testing purposes
            return

test = Parser()    
test.query()
```

When you call a method like `test.query()`, the `query` method is invoked, and `test` is passed in as the `self` parameter.  Also, within your methods, when you want to refer to the object, you have to use the `self` parameter to access the attributes explicitly.

One last point: in your `query()` method, you return within the for loop, so you'll only execute one iteration of the loop, rather than iterating over all of `database`.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh!

You are calling `query` on an object (called `test`) of type `Parser`. Under the hood, what python is doing, is calling `Parser.query(test)`.

This is why when you write a method inside a class, you should always include `self` as the first parameter.

As others mention, changing your function signature to `def query(self)` would solve this problem

Hope that helps

Comment: Oh, I only want to call Parser.query()